# jquery countdown timer for 30 minutes save in cookie, remain continue onload/unload page

Tags: jquery, cookies, countdowntimer

i used plugin [jquery countdown](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html) timer and it work fine but how do i save in cookie so that whenever user refresh/reload page and the timer still continue. This is what i've so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

if (!$.cookie('offerTimer')){ 
    var timerSet = 30 * 60; //30 minutes
    $.cookie('offerTimer', timerSet, { expires: 7, path: '/' });
}
var runTimer = $.cookie('offerTimer');
$('#defaultCountdown').countdown({until: runTimer, format: 'DHMS'});

});
```

As addition: maybe with some code that get server time? So that user cannot manipulate the cookie?

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick, but still just save in cookie.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

if (!$.cookie('offerTimer')){
var now = $.now(); //get first time log page
var timerSet = 30 * 60; //30 minutes
$.cookie('firstTime', now, { expires: 7, path: '/' });
$.cookie('offerTimer', timerSet, { expires: 7, path: '/' });
var runTimer = $.cookie('offerTimer');
} else {  
var currentTime = $.now();
var usedTime = (currentTime - $.cookie('firstTime'))/1000; //calculate and convert into seconds
var runTimer = $.cookie('offerTimer') - usedTime; 
}
$('#defaultCountdown').countdown({until: runTimer, format: 'DHMS'});

});
```